# How do I sum all rows of a specific header in an excel file with c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a excel table with 1 sheet. That sheet has headers in row 1.
One of the headers is Amount.

I want to read all rows from that header and get the sum of it independently of the number or rows, which is never the same, into a variable of type float.

I'm doing this with c#.

I open the workbook, I get the active sheet and then nothing, I get blocked.

How do I go about this?
Rui Martins

Comment: I just sit there looking at it and nothing comes out. I'm blocked.

Comment: How are you "getting the active sheet"? Does that sheet have something like `Columns` or `Rows`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use OleDB instead of Excel.Interop

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\test.xls;" + 
              "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
using(OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(con))
{
    c.Open();
    string selectString = "SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM [Sheet1$]";
    using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(selectString))
    {
       cmd1.Connection = c;
 var result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
       Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
 }
```

This example use the old `Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0` provider, but works equally with the new `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

Comment: In the case of this application. Since the workbook is actually open, I have to use Interop

Comment: Don't know, I have tried with workbook open and OleDb works, probably there are some options to prevent sharing of open workbooks.

Comment: And there's another thing. I don't know where the file is located. It's the user of the aplication that opens it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, you should be able to loop through the rows and get the total by adding the cell values altogether.

[MSDN article on how to retrieve excel cell values.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff921204.aspx)